# Duplicate CloudPage or template

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage

Built a CloudPage(landing page) with Content Builder UI.  Now that I have this built, is there ANY way to duplicate the page?  Will need a few variations over the course of time and I'd rather not create a new landing page and copy over the elements one by one to achieve the same look.

NOTE: using the Classic design/code view is not an option.  I need it to be 'easily' editable for some of the campaign managers to swap out text without getting into HTML.

BONUS: If copying HTML is the only way to do this; is there an element tag I can append to the source HTML so that the content blocks render within the Content Builder UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing that is available to clone a CloudPage is to create content from existing in the Page Properties of that landing page.

[image: Create from Existing Content]

Otherwise, your only options are to copy and page if it is HTML code or open up an incognito window of the page you want to copy and manually rebuild it with the new landing page on another window.

Comment: I saw the `Start from Existing Content` but that function excludes any page built using the Content Builder UI.  Bummer. I can only duplicate classic content or code resources.

Comment: I agree. Kind of a pain. It should be an update for the product team to add to CloudPages